# What good Open GL abstractions in objective-c are there?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos3d

I have been looking around for a while now, trying to find some easier 3D framework for iOS. Cocos3D looks cool to work with in iOS, but I seems quite beta(?) and the documentation provided seems not enough to understand how to work with it.

So I have been searching the web for similar libs without any luck, even for something close to a tutorial. Does anyone know an easy library for creating some basic 3D demos?

I would like to create a demo simulating flying over some simple terrain/ground and somehow be using GL for this. Any directions are appreciated.

Comment: for OS X use Scene Kit, for iOS Nineveh is possibly the most complete solution http://nineveh.gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cocos3d** is actively developed and supported, and is currently being used in dozens of apps and games. It now supports the iOS, OSX and Android platforms.

**cocos3d 2.0** is recommended for new development. It is stable, actively supported, and is nearing its first formal release as a packaged distribution, which is planned for end Dec 2013/early Jan, 2014.

As for documentation, I agree that it is woefully deficient. We will be introducing a new website and Wiki around the time of the formal 2.0 release, which should help to remedy this moving forward.

Right now, your best bet for learning **cocos3d** is to review the implementation of the `CC3DemoMashUp` demo app, which demos almost all of the major features of **cocos3d**.

Relevant to your specific demo idea, the `CC3DemoMashUp` demo includes a dragon flying over a scene. The dragon also demonstrates blending between animation tracks.

Comment: Do you have any ref. cases that are in the app stores/markets? Is the development C++ for cross-platform compability? or is it java/obj-c?

Comment: There is a somewhat hodge-podge list of released apps [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/tell-us-about-your-cocos3d-app/).

To provide cross-platform support, cocos3d has partnered with [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/). You can write your entire app in nothin'-but-Obj-C, and port to Android using Apportable's tool suite.